# Identity Server 6 - Add Additional User Tables And Data

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, .net-6.0, duende-identity-server

I'm fairly new to Identity Server and ASP Identity Core.

I have a .Net6 ASP project set up using Identity Server 6 and it has an ApplicationUser model from Identity Core. I'm using Entity to handle my database stuff.

Lets say I want to make an API that stores the User's favorite cars and their ratings of these cars.

How do I approach this?

1. Do I just stuff all the new data into custom fields inside ApplicationUser?
   This would mean my API's database is the Identity Server / Identity Core database.

   ```
    namespace IdentityServer.Models
    {
     public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
     {
        // Add custom fields.
        public List<Car>? Cars { get; set; }
        public List<CarRatings>? CarRatings { get; set; }
        public string? OtherData {get; set; }

      }
   }
   ```
2. Do I create a separate database table using One-To-Many / Foreign Keys inside the ApplicationUser class? Again, still using Identity Server / Core as my main database.

   ```
   namespace IdentityServer.Models
   {
     public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
     {
        // Add Other Tables
        public ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }     // Entity Navigation Property

     }

     public class Cars {

        public List<Car>? Cars { get; set; }
        public List<CarRatings>? CarRatings { get; set; }
        public string? OtherData {get; set; }

        // Maybe has a foreign key if navigation property isn't enough.
     }
   }
   ```
3. A separate database for my API entirely? All the car stuff inside a API_Car database. No idea how I would link the separate database to the Users in Identity Server / Identity Core. Maybe the separate database has a UserID field it copies from IdentityServer?

I'm thinking that anything user specific must be saved in the IdentityServer/Identity Core database. The other APIs will just check that the user is Authorized, and provide general information from their own databases? So the Car_API will have getCars() and return a list of all available cars but the cars the user wants to review will be saved in IdentityCore database.

Doesn't really sound right... I'd want separation of concerns. If user data is inside the IdentityServer database I'm tightly coupled to it and can't easily swap IdentityServer for something else in the future.

**What's industry best practice for designing API databases to work with Identity Server?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found of doing this si to let Identity Server, or whatever is doing the Authentication, just do the authentication.

In your other API just have a userId field that you can populate by doing a get request to IdentityServer's userInfo endpoint.

Do the userInfo request anytime you need user information like Id, email address, name, age etc.

ONLY store the user's Id in a userID field in your API. The user Guid won't change, whereas the user's email address or surname might. You would then have a user with different details in IdentityServer's database and your API database.